# How did Lark prepare this?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible-fallout

In MI: Fallout, Lark is setup by the IMF team when one of them replaces Lane in his cell. He reveals his plan and is arrested.

Eventually, IMF is surrounded by CIA agents, but it turns out that Lark had agents there, and he kills an IMF member and escapes.

How did Lark have agents there when he didn't know he was being setup?

Answer (score 3):

As a spy, maybe you have to always assume you're being setup or that the situation will go poorly and have backup plans? It seems feasible that since he had infiltrated the CIA that others could have as well, or that he turned other agents to his side. It's possible Lark anticipated his boss at the CIA finding out and orchestrated his men being in the squad that would come for him, or maybe his men were already there posing as another group from the CIA.